# Azure Function save to file without content header

Tags: azure, post, azure-functions

I am using the following Azure Function to upload a text file. When the text file is saved to the disk a header is part of the output probably because the request body is saved to the file. How can I save only the contents of the file without the header?

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest req)
        {
            var stream = string.Empty;
            byte[] bytes= {};
            if (req.Body != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
                stream = bytes.Length.ToString();

                using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    ms.WriteTo(file);
                }
            }
                        return new OkResult();              
        }
```

The saved text file contains a header like this:

```
----------------------------900677394929774652406440
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testing.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Here is the Postman setup

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code,

```
 var file = req.Form.Files[0];
 await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

;

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan thanks for your suggestion but I am having problem evaluating the form field. Getting the following error 'req.Form.Files[0]' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' any ideas why thats happening?

Comment: Thanks alot, turns out I was always looking at the Watch property which is not the same as actually running the code